# Firestore connection issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing admin pannel on laravel with firebase database. It is working well with real time database but  in case of firestore it gives error on collection().

classes I am importing are

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Kreait\Firebase\Database;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
```

Here is code of realtime database which is working fine.

```
   $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/errand.json');
    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
    $reference = $database->getReference('tokens');
    $value = $reference->getValue();
```

but issue arises in firestore in collection() and its code is

```
   $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/foodTruck.json');
   $database =$factory->createFirestore();
   $docRef = $database->collection('drivers');
   $snapshot = $docRef->snapshot();
```

here is error thrown by laravel:

```
Error
Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Factory::collection()
```

I also installed gRPC etc but not getting rid of this issue. Anyone please help me.

Comment: I'm hopeful that @jeromegamez will see this post and answer. That's the maintainer for the library you are using and they've answered other posts in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you should have done `$database =$factory->createFirestore()->database();` instead of using the object returned from the factory. if I look into the documentation, and the error, it looks like you are having the wrong object, you should have `Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient` instead of the `Kreait\Firebase\Factory` at this point, but I could be totally wrong. To add something => here is the doc https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/5.x/docs/cloud-firestore.rst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed this code

```
   $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/foodTruck.json');
   $database =$factory->createFirestore();
   $docRef = $database->collection('drivers');
   $snapshot = $docRef->snapshot();
```

to this one

```
    $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/mobznew.json');
    $database = $factory->createFirestore()->database();
    $usersRef = $database->collection('users');
    $snapshot = $usersRef->documents();
    foreach ($snapshot as $user) {
    $age = array("uid"=>$user['userId'],"email"=>$user['email']);
    $data[]=$age;        
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

this worked fine for me. Special thanks to @Frankich